# Automatically scroll multiline TextFormField when it extends the maxLines attribute

Tags: textfield, autoscroll, flutter

I'm implementing a TextFormField with the maxLines attribute set to 3. How can I make the TextFormField scroll down once the user starts with his fourth line? At the moment the cursor is just not visible anymore until the user scrolls down by hand. Is there a way to do this automatically?

This behaviour is actually featured in the flutter_gallery app in the 'Text fields' example. Just type a long text to the 'Live story' input until it reaches the fourth line.
The important parts of my code actually look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFormFieldDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Form(
        child: new TextFormField(
          maxLines: 3,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So far I have found no workaround for this issue.
This issue affects both iOS and android.

Comment: PS: This also affects single line TextFields. One would expect the text to scroll to the left once the end of the line is reached, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a missing feature in the Flutter Framework, I've filed a bug to get it resolved: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9365

Answer (score 19):

Our team accomplished this by nesting some existing widgets:

```
// create the illusion of a beautifully scrolling text box
return new Container(
    color: Colors.gray,
  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),

  child: new ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: new BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: _contextWidth(),
      maxWidth: _contextWidth(),
      minHeight: AppMeasurements.isLandscapePhone(context) ? 25.0 : 25.0,
      maxHeight: 55.0,
    ),

    child: new SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      reverse: true,

        // here's the actual text box
        child: new TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          maxLines: null, //grow automatically
          focusNode: mrFocus,
          controller: _textController,
          onSubmitted: currentIsComposing ? _handleSubmitted : null,
          decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: ''Please enter a lot of text',
          ),
        ),
        // ends the actual text box

      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

We had help from [Darky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394265/darky) to get widget ordering and the correct widgets to make it work.

Comment: maxLInes=null is awesome

Comment: beautiful hack <3

Comment: Did anyone got this running for the CupertinoTextBox? Though MaxLines=null is also supposed to create a growing field, no scroll bar shows up

Comment: @w461: using a CupertinoTextField will add scrollbars automatically but maxLines can't be null. Scrollbars are added the moment the contents of the text field exceeds maxLines. E.g. if maxLines is 3 and the text occupies 4 lines, a scrollbar is added.

Answer (score 6):

With the latest flutter 1.20.4, this text field will scroll when it rich the max hight.

```
       Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
             child: TextField(
                maxLines: null,
                 .......
                )
            )
```

If you are using the Textfield inside Raw or column wrap it in `Expanded` widget

Comment: It works fantastically!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `BoxConstraints` and set `maxHeight` of your TextField

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: TextField(
      maxLines: null,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve this with ScrollController.

```
ScrollController textFieldScrollController = ScrollController();

TextField(
  scrollController: textFieldScrollController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  minLines: null,
  maxLines: null,
  onChanged: (value) {
    textFieldScrollController.jumpTo(textFieldScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
  },
),
```

Comment: Great,it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work like this. Hope it helps!

```
return new Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                 side: BorderSide(
                   color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                   width: 1
                 ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: TextField(
                      maxLines: null,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Use `TextFormField()` widget & set `minLines=`  and `maxLines=` .
The missing thing is here Scroll indicator.

```
 TextFormField(
                    minLines: 3,
                    maxLines: 3,
                    key: _messageValueKey,
                    decoration: _inputDecoration,
                  ),
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add the 'reverse: true' to your Scrollable Widget, like so:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 130.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          reverse: true,
          child: Text(
            '$message',
            maxLines: 2,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```