# Flutter - Textfield label overflow cutting off text

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter project, I have implemented a Form with a `TextFormField`, we have some fields with really long labels, and because they are so long, Flutter us cutting the text off and adding ... in the end, is it possible to set the overflow so it makes the label text in to 2 lines instead of cutting the text off?

```dart
TextFormField(
          key: GlobalKey(),
          controller: _textEditingController,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          obscureText: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          decoration: widget.decorations.copyWith(
            errorText:
                widget.field["error"] != null ? widget.field["error"] : null,
            labelText: "A VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG LABEL",
            hintText: widget.field["helpText"],
            helperStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          onFieldSubmitted: widget.onFieldSubmitted,
          onSaved: widget.onSaved,
          onTap: widget.onTap,
        ),
```

Comment: Try this, https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I don't think this will work for a textfield label,

Comment: Why not like plain html, you add a title attribute and when someone hover on it the label will appear, a trick.

Comment: I am sure the `labelText: "A VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG LABEL",` requires a string and you can not assign it a Widget

Comment: `maxLines` attribute available for `TextFormField` mentioned in your example here. Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900387/multi-line-textfield-in-flutter and this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348254/automatically-scroll-multiline-textformfield-when-it-extends-the-maxlines-attrib

Comment: Sorry I am talking about the label cutting off, not the value.

Comment: I got to know, I saw another thread which is telling exactly same that it will increase height of field not `labelText`. One more thing if you have only one line then you can use `hintText`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208041/discussion-between-utkarsh-dubey-and-user3057745).

Comment: You need to think differently it's still a bug, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30439

Comment: Try CSS if possible, like [CSS Scrolling Text](https://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/css-scrolling-text.cfm) or `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Answer (score 3):

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942523/multiline-string-for-textformstring-validator) while I was trying to solve the same problem. Try using the `decoration` property with the `errorMaxLines` property set to a number greater than 1.
E.g.

```
TextField(
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     errorMaxLines: 2,),)
```

Comment: The solution  you have provided is about error text not labelText

Answer (score 1):

It works for me....

TextFormField(

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 label: Text(
      "A VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG LABEL",
    ),)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to work to allow the 2nd line of text but doesn't maintain the same space between the bottom of the 2nd line of the label and the field itself.

Answer (score 0):

I worked through all the other answers, and this is the only one that worked for me.
The Container has a transform property allowing us to essentially use negative margins, use it in Decoration to give more space for 2 lines of a label which don't encroach on your field.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
    label: Container(
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -15.0, 0.0),
      child: const Text(
          'Label text here. This also allows you to have long lable text as you can use the space for 2 lines.'),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use labelStyle's overFlow parameter to do as u want;

```dart
labelText: "hii there",
labelStyle: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow...... )
```